# Error running commands with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to install rbenv in a centos container using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-centos-7).
When i run these commands in bash myself they work but when using docker build i get the error below.

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN yum install -y sudo git vim git-core zlib zlib-devel gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel make bzip2 autoconf automake libtool bison curl sqlite-devel

RUN cd
RUN git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
RUN echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN exec $SHELL

RUN git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
RUN echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN exec $SHELL
RUN source ~/.bash_profile

RUN rbenv install -v 2.2.1
RUN rbenv global 2.2.1

RUN echo "gem: --no-document" > ~/.gemrc

RUN gem install bundler
```

output

```
Step 9 : RUN exec $SHELL
 ---> Running in 021180fff90b
 ---> 62ed2f1faaa6
Removing intermediate container 021180fff90b
Step 10 : RUN source ~/.bash_profile
 ---> Running in 89e10052c73b
/root/.bash_profile: line 14: rbenv: command not found
 ---> f819228f98c2
Removing intermediate container 89e10052c73b
Step 11 : RUN rbenv install -v 2.2.1
 ---> Running in a4304fe37e18
/bin/sh: rbenv: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c rbenv install -v 2.2.1' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source command is in a RUN, so it is forgotten in the next command